# AJAX call to Justin TV API failing with JSON format

Tags: ajax, json, api, jsonp

I'm trying to make a simple AJAX call to the Justin TV API, which seems to be failing consistently.

When making the AJAX call with `url1`, the console reports `Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success"}`, yet it falls into the error function of the AJAX call. When visiting the URL with my browser, I notice the returned data is `[{ ... json ...}]`.

When making the AJAX call with 'url', the call passes, entering the success function. I notice the returned object is `{ ...json... }`.

How do I get a valid JSON object out of the AJAX request for `url1`?

Here's a snip of what I'm doing:

```
var url1 = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json"
var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";

channelNames = "";
for (channelName in streams)
{
    channelNames = channelNames + ',' + channelName;
}
channelNames = channelNames.slice(1);
console.log(channelNames);
console.log(url1);
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { channel : channelNames },
    success: function(data) 
    {
        console.log(data);
        if(data.streams.length > 0)
        {
            $("#streamStatus").html("<ul class='zebra'>");          
            for(i = 0; i < data.streams.length; i++)
            {
                stream = data.streams[i];
                channel = data.streams[i].channel;
                listItem = "<li id='stream"+i+"'>";
                streamName = "<span class='name'>" + streams[stream.name.slice(10)] + "</span>";
                viewers = "<span class='viewers'>viewers:" + stream.viewers + "</span>";
                gameName = "<div class='game'>" + ((channel.game != null) ? channel.game : "No Game Specified") + "</div>";
                listItem += streamName + viewers + gameName + "</li>"; 
                screenCap = "<div class='screenCap' style='display:none;'>" + channel.screen_cap_url_small + "</div>"
                $("#streamStatus ul.zebra").append(listItem);
                $("#streamStatus ul.zebra").append(screenCap);
                //console.log(channel);
            }
            $("#streamStatus").append("</ul>");
        }
    },
    error: function(data) 
    { 
        console.log(data);
    }
```

EDIT: Here is the working solution...

```
var url1 = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json"
var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";

channelNames = "";
for (channelName in streams)
{
    channelNames = channelNames + ',' + channelName;
}
channelNames = channelNames.slice(1);
console.log(channelNames);
console.log(url1);
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    data: { channel : channelNames },
    success: function(data) 
    {
         ...
    },
    error: function(data) 
    { 
        console.log(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `jsonp` as the `dataType` in the `ajax` call. They're not interchangeable.

As you've noted yourself, the data returned from `url1` is JSON, **not** JSONP: JSONP requires wrapping the returned JSON data in a javascript function call.

A mismatch like this between `dataType` and the data in the response body will always cause the `ajax` call to fail.

Comment: The problem is that when I switch the call to not use JSONP, the AJAX call does not succeed. The statusText is set to "error", readystate=0, etc.

I read at http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/ that JQuery handles the callback hook for JSONP for you, so you can use 'success' and 'error' as normal.

Comment: After adding jsonp: "jsonp" to the AJAX method call, things started working. I'm not exactly sure why, but hopefully if anyone else sees this, it might help them too.

Comment: It didn't work, no. I believe the API provider only supports JSONP. I was getting failures back from the AJAX call when I switched the datatype to 'json', but every call was succeeding with 'jsonp'.